# In Airflow version 2, create a DAG to Archive Mysql table into bigquery

Tags: python, airflow, airflow-2.x

I basically want to fetch the data older than 2 weeks from a my_sql_table called "testing_monitor_archive" and put it into a bigquery table "monitoring_table". I am using airflow version 2.1.4 currently. This is the DAG which i have created currently which is failing in "GCSCreateBucketOperator" saying invalid operators {provide_context
python_callable,object} which even i agree since these were the parameters of the operator "GoogleCloudStorageBucketOperator" which is depreciated in version 2 now. Now since i know "GCSCreateBucketOperator" has no such upload operators, how can i upload the results of the mysql task "fetch_data" as a CSV into my cloud bucket and then put into Bigquery, please help.

My code -

```
from datetime import timedelta, datetime
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.mysql_operator import MySqlOperator
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.operators.gcs import GCSCreateBucketOperator
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.transfers.gcs_to_bigquery import GCSToBigQueryOperator
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago

# Default arguments for the DAG
default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'start_date': days_ago(2),
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
}

# Create a new DAG
dag = DAG(
    'my_data_pipeline',
    default_args=default_args,
    schedule_interval='0 0 * * *', # run daily at midnight
)

# SQL query to fetch data older than 2 weeks
query = """
    SELECT * FROM testing_monitor_archive
    WHERE CREATE_TS < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 WEEK)
"""

# Create a task to execute the SQL query
fetch_data = MySqlOperator(
    task_id='fetch_data',
    mysql_conn_id='my_mysql_connection', # connection details for the MySQL database
    sql=query,
    dag=dag,
)

# GCS bucket and object name where the data will be stored
bucket = 'mysql-archive-gcs-bucket'
object_name = 'data/{{ execution_date }}.csv'

def retrieve_data(**kwargs):
    ti= kwargs['ti']
    data=ti.xcom_pull(task_ids="fetch_data")
    return data

# Create a task to upload the data to GCS
upload_to_gcs = GCSCreateBucketOperator(
    task_id='upload_to_gcs',
    # src='{{ task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids="fetch_data") }}', # source is the output of the fetch_data task
    bucket_name=bucket,
    provide_context=True,
    python_callable=retrieve_data,
    object=object_name,
    gcp_conn_id='gcp_conn_id', # connection details for GCS
    dag=dag,
)

# BigQuery dataset and table name where the data will be loaded
dataset_id = 'archive_dataset'
table_id = 'monitoring_table'

# Create a task to load the data from GCS to BigQuery
load_to_bigquery = GCSToBigQueryOperator(
    task_id='load_to_bigquery',
    bucket=bucket,
    source_objects=[object_name],
    destination_project_dataset_table=f"{dataset_id}.{table_id}",
    google_cloud_storage_conn_id='gcp_conn_id', # connection details for GCS
    bigquery_conn_id='gcp_conn_id', # connection details for BigQuery
    dag=dag,
)

# Set the dependencies between the tasks
fetch_data >> upload_to_gcs >> load_to_bigquery
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in one step using MySQLToGCSOperator (https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/_api/airflow/providers/google/cloud/transfers/mysql_to_gcs/index.html).

Based on your code:

```
upload_to_gcs = MySQLToGCSOperator(
    task_id='upload_to_gcs',
    sql=query,
    bucket=bucket,
    filename=object_name,
    mysql_conn_id='my_mysql_connection',
    gcp_conn_id='gcp_conn_id',
    export_format='csv',
    dag=dag)
```

The next step is to create an external table based on a csv file.

Comment: Thank you. Also, while my bigquery table got created but i see the headerrow from CSV having column names is coming as first row inside bigquery table which is wrong since i want that to become schema of my table... any idea how to overcome this?

Comment: When creating a table in the system (in the GUI) you have the option to skip rows